# Merging images together isn't really working out

Tags: php, gd

I can't seem to merge 2 images for some reason and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. This is still a bit new to me. here is the code I have:

```
$source = 'http://localhost:8888/develop/trunk/develop/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/card01-80x80.jpg';
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
// Make the background transparent
imagecolortransparent($im, $black);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagejpeg($im, WP_UPLOADS_PATH . 'post-image-generator/1.jpg');


//merge images
$thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
$destination = imagecreatefromjpeg(WP_UPLOADS_PATH . 'post-image-generator/1.jpg');


imagecopymerge($destination, $thumb, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100);


imagejpeg($destination, WP_UPLOADS_PATH . 'post-image-generator/1.jpg');

echo "
    <style></style>
    <img src='" . WP_UPLOADS_URL . 'post-image-generator/1.jpg' . "' />
        ";


imagedestroy($thumb);
imagedestroy($destination);
imagedestroy($im);
```

It generates the following:

[image: generated image]

but should also include the following image:

[image: missing image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I have a little experience with this. Let me go dig up my old scripts and I might have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell without actually testing it, it's this:

imagecopymerge($destination, $thumb, 0, 0, 0, 0, **0, 0,** 100);

The area you're copying from starts at 0,0 in $thumb, and the width and height of the area to be copied is 0 and 0. Since the source picture is 80x80 and you want the whole thing to be copied to the top left corner of the first image, you'd need to change it to:

imagecopymerge($destination, $thumb, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 80, 100);

This copies the whole 80-pixel image to the top left corner of $destination.

Comment: I had set the wrong size and for some reason I set it back to 0... no idea why. I'm totally clueless why I did this :) Thank you for your help.